# How to Create a DbContextFactory in .NETCore 3.1 & Blazor

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm following guidelines in how to setup EF Core to work safely in Blazor & .NET Core 3.1.
The MS documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In the instructions, advice is to create a DbContextFactory which is used to create a dbcontext in each service.  All makes sense in the Blazor world, but the code won't compile as
AddDbContextFactory does not exist.  If there's another way to do it in .Net Core 3.1/ EF Core 3 - I can't see it.

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<ContactContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlite($"Data Source={nameof(ContactContext.ContactsDb)}.db")
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found [this extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/3770baac03f8085cc1258d89a765260c6dfc0f9e/aspnetcore/blazor/common/samples/3.x/BlazorServerEFCoreSample/BlazorServerDbContextExample/Data/FactoryExtensions.cs#L22-L41) that the Microsoft docs page is using in its sample github project:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextFactory<TContext>(
    this IServiceCollection collection,
    Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null,
    ServiceLifetime contextAndOptionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton
)
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    // instantiate with the correctly scoped provider
    collection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(IDbContextFactory<TContext>),
        sp => new DbContextFactory<TContext>(sp),
        contextAndOptionsLifetime
    ));

    // dynamically run the builder on each request
    collection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(DbContextOptions<TContext>),
        sp => GetOptions<TContext>(optionsAction, sp),
        contextAndOptionsLifetime
    ));

    return collection;
}
```

The all-important `interface IDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/3770baac03f8085cc1258d89a765260c6dfc0f9e/aspnetcore/blazor/common/samples/3.x/BlazorServerEFCoreSample/BlazorServerDbContextExample/Data/IDbContextFactory.cs):

```
/// <summary>Factory to create new instances of <see cref="DbContext"/>.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="TContext">The type of <seealso cref="DbContext"/> to create.</typeparam>
public interface IDbContextFactory<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>Generate a new <see cref="DbContext"/>.</summary>
    /// <returns>A new instance of <see cref="TContext"/>.</returns>
    TContext CreateDbContext();
}
```

And the factory class is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/3770baac03f8085cc1258d89a765260c6dfc0f9e/aspnetcore/blazor/common/samples/3.x/BlazorServerEFCoreSample/BlazorServerDbContextExample/Data/DbContextFactory.cs):

```
public class DbContextFactory<TContext> : IDbContextFactory<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

    public DbContextFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public TContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        if (provider == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"You must configure an instance of IServiceProvider");
        }

        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TContext>(provider);
    }
}
```

`GetOptions` method:

```
private static DbContextOptions<TContext> GetOptions<TContext>(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> action, IServiceProvider sp = null) 
    where TContext: DbContext 
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder < TContext > ();
    if (sp != null) 
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp);
    }
    action?.Invoke(optionsBuilder);
    return optionsBuilder.Options;
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is optimized for Blazor. If you want to use this in some other kind of project, make sure you change the lifetime default to Scoped, or else your contexts will be injected as singletons which may not be what you want (the default is usually scoped).

Comment: FYI: If you try to implement that, you also need to copy the GetOptions method from the link. Even more important: this code will not run when you have empty constructor on your DbContext (AFAIK ActivatorUtilities get the first context).

Comment: Link is now broken :( Looking for the GetOptions function

Comment: Found on wayback:
private static DbContextOptions<TContext> GetOptions<TContext>(
            Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> action,
            IServiceProvider sp = null) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
            if (sp != null)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp);
            }
            action?.Invoke(optionsBuilder);
            return optionsBuilder.Options;
        }

Answer (score 5):

`AddDbContextFactory` will be introduced in .NET Core 5. See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-7/.

Comment: Yep I saw that & look forward to it,but the 3.1 documentation also describes it in sample code.  Hopefully there's accurate 3.1 guidance somewhere.

Comment: But I can assure you that it doesn’t exist in the current (3.1) codebase.

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked to gives you the code (albeit in pieces) to roll your own.

You will have to add the `AddDbContextFactory<TContext>` class and the FactoryExtensions to your project. Download the sample app there to make it complete.

And when you upgrade to net5 just replace it with the library version.