# Is it safe to inject the DbContext service into a Razor component of an ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an existing ASP.NET Core (MVC) project. Part of my app requires client interactivity, so I've added support for Razor components.
For using Razor components in my existing MVC project, I have:

1. Added server-side Blazor in the `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
...
services.AddServerSideBlazor()
```

2. Mapped the Blazor SignalR Hub in the `Configure()` method:

```
...
app.UseEndPoints(endpoints =>
{
    ...
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
});
...
```

3. I also added an `_Imports.razor` file to my application root.

I'm planning to include the Razor components via the [`<component>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper) tag in my views managed by controllers:

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered">
```

I want to enable database operations using EF Core in my Razor component. I have added my `AppDbContext` service to the DI container using the `AddDbContext()` method in <kbd>Startup.cs</kbd>. I was either planning to:

- Inject my DB Context using the `@inject` directive directly in the component
  OR
- pass it as a parameter to the component by first injecting the DB Context into my parent MVC view.

However, this is discouraged in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0#database-access-5x) of the documentation:

> EF Core provides the AddDbContext extension for ASP.NET Core apps that registers the context as a scoped service by default. In Blazor Server apps, scoped service registrations can be problematic because the instance is shared across components within the user's circuit. DbContext isn't thread safe and isn't designed for concurrent use.

The documentation states that it is the case for Blazor server apps. But what about an ASP.NET Core application that just uses Razor components?

Comment: This is where you use DBContextFactory instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63936399/how-to-create-a-dbcontextfactory-in-netcore-3-1-blazor

Comment: If it is not Blazor server, that does not apply. Blazor server maintains a signal R connection that impacts IoC scope.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are working with Blazor components, you need to be cautious about injecting DbContext. You may have problems in two different scenarios:

1. Two different processes in the components try to access injected DbContext at the same time. For example a timer is updating information on the page by reading from db periodically.
2. Another process or background task is changing database somewhere in the application.

In the first scenario you will receive an exception showing that two different process are accessing the same resource (Thread safety issue). In the second scenario you cannot access the updated value in the database because of the caching.
Thus, I recommend to avoid using injected database if you are not sure about concurrency or updating database anywhere in your application. You may find some proposed solutions that you can search online such as:

1. Change DbContext lifetime to Transient.
2. Use IDbContextFactory
3. Create new instance per operation